# MS Project - Application Crashes When Opening VBE & Master File

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

Project ver 1902 (Build 11328.20438 Click to Run), Windows 10

I have a particular master file (42 sub projects) that crashes the Project application any time I attempt to open the VBE or run a macro. I suspected that a macro I had written was the problem and I reset the Global.MPT and disabled all macros. It still crashes if I attempt to open the VBE with that same master project file.  I've tried reinstalling the Office suite, it still crashes. If I don't attempt to open the VBE, I can interact with the file normally, and no other master or individual project file produces this issue. I tried recreating a new version of this master file from scratch, still crashes.

[image: Opening VBE]

[image: Crashin' Down]

Comment: Hi SeaSky, this question is [off-topic](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at PM.SE. This could fit better at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-project+vba). I'd close it, but being the case there's already an answer on it I'll leave it to the community discretion.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming this master did not have this problem previously and that the overall size of the master and subprojects has not grown significantly, this could be a case of corruption in one or more of your files. This is unfortunately not uncommon, especially with larger and more complex schedules.

Removing macros, restoring the global.mpt and rebuilding the master schedule were appropriate steps.

### Other simple things to try:

- Try the master on a more powerful computer (e.g. more memory, faster/more processors).
- Rename the subprojects to remove spaces and special characters & create a new master.
- Create a master project with just some of the files (to see if fewer subprojects and/or eliminating a particular subproject resolves the issue).

If those steps fail to resolve the issue, consider rebuilding the 42 subprojects. Try saving them in xml format and then open the xml file as a new project and do a Save-As to a new location. Then create a new master.

Note: One thing to keep in mind about corruption in MS Project files is that it can linger undetected for some time. Often times restoring a corrupt file from backup is not sufficient as the 'seed' of corruption is in that earlier-version of the file and the restored file will soon become corrupt as well. That's why rebuilding is a safer route.